# Разделение массива по равенству двух частей

Tags: алгоритм

Как разделить массив на две равные части, суммы элементов которых наиболее близки к равенству.

Как разделить массив по на две части, я знаю. Но не могу придумать, как сделать? чтобы суммы элементов этих двух частей были равны. Прошу подсказать алгоритм.

Для тех, кто просил уточнить условие: массив делится на две равные части, количество элементов первой части = количеству элементов второй. Также сумма элементов первой части равна или наиболее близка к равенству второй части.

Comment: А что делать, если у вас не могут быть равны части, как не дели? Можно перемещать элементы?

Comment: входящий массив должен быть четным. Перемещать можно

Comment: Вам нужен сам алгоритм или как это сделать на определенном языке?

Comment: мне нужно реализовать на C#

Comment: С этим сложнее... Пока нет другого ответа, я мог бы показать, как бы делал это я на PHP.

Comment: можете алгоритм просто подсказать

Comment: а можно узнать в какой области необходим данный алгоритм?

Comment: так что важнее - количество элементов в левой и правой части или сумма их **значений** в этих частях?

Comment: @Merlin и то и другое)

Comment: а при разделении массива перемещать элементы можно? (в условии это не оговорено) или надо только найти?

Comment: @Merlin я даже уже не знаю как еще можно понять. Что значит перемещать? Менять местами можно сколько угодно, главное чтоб в двух подмассивах было одинаковое количество элементов.

Comment: > Менять местами можно сколько угодно

разделение не всегда подразумевает под собой изменение, но так как в задаче нет прямого запрета на изменение порядка элементов, значит можно, это все что я хотел выяснить.

Answer (score 13):

- Вы переформулировали так называемую [`Partition Problem`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) Это известная `Weakly NP-Complete` задача, для которой существует псевдополиномиальный алгоритм и *примерный* полиномиальный алгоритм.

> Подробнее можете почитать, пройдя по первой ссылке или, например, здесь: [**Divide list in two parts that their sum is closest to each other.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479479/divide-list-in-two-parts-that-their-sum-closest-to-each-other)

- Если вас устроит примерное решение, то используйте `O(N log N)` жадный алгоритм
  [image]

*(Для тех, кто сидит в комментариях :)*

- Условие деления массива на части одинаковой длины не влияет на `NP`-полноту задачи *(она все еще `NPC`).* Доказательство этого факта с точки зрения теории алгоритмов может звучать примерно так:

> - Сведем общую задачу `Partition Problem (PP)` к задаче с двумя равными частями `Equally Sized Partition Problem (ESPP)`, то есть покажем, что `ESPP` включает в качестве частного случая задачу `PP`.
> - Рассмотрим последовательность элементов длиной `2k`, из которых `k` являются нулями. Теперь, решив эту задачу с помощью алгоритма `ESPP`, мы получим две последовательности длины `k`, разница сумм которых минимальна. Поскольку нулевые элементы не меняют суммы, то мы можем "перегнать" их из одной последовательности в другую, соответственно, сводя задачу к `PP`.

- Раз мы доказали, что задача `NPC`, то полиномиального алгоритма решения этой задачи не существует. Можете воспользоваться псевдополиномиальным алгоритмом из википедии, адаптировав его для себя или *любым жадным алгоритмом из тех, что предложен ниже.*

Comment: Но ведь просят, чтобы A и B были **равного** размера. Этот алгоритм так не работает.

Comment: авп, не просят, я тоже считал вариант с равными половинками.. да и кстати, если разница не делится на 2, но массив не поделится на равные части..

Comment: @avp, я думаю, что ТС, говоря о равности, имел в виду не равные по размеру массивы, а всё же равные по сумме значений. Но тут бы неплохо, чтоб сам автор уточнил.

Comment: @Deonis почему-то я подумал тоже о равности и в размере массивов.

Comment: В **заголовке** вопроса **написано**

    две равные части, суммы элементов которых наиболее близки к равности

Comment: Котик_хочет_кушать, как в данном выполниться условие sum(A) < sum(B), если первоначально сумма их элементов равна 0?

Answer (score 5):

*В продолжение к моим коментариям*

В заголовке темы, вы указываете, что если не абсолютно равны, то максимально приближены к равенству. Тогда, на PHP я сделал следующим образом:

1. Посчитал сумму значений массива и разделил её на два
2. Отсортировал массив по убыванию значений
3. Перебираем отсортированный масси

> сумма_массива1 = 0;
>
> сумма_массива2 = 0;
>
> если (сумма*массива1 <= сумма*массива2 || сумма*массива2 >= пол*общей_суммы){
>
> ```
> добавить значение в массив1
>
> сумма_массива1 += значение;
> ```
>
> } в*другом*случае {
>
> ```
> добавить значение в массив2
>
> сумма_массива2 += значение;
> ```
>
> }

Код на PHP (проверить можно его тут - http://writecodeonline.com/php/):

```
$arr = array(10,68,30,28,34,74,52,20,176,18,86,14,22,4); // исходный массив
rsort($arr,SORT_NUMERIC); // сортируем по значениям в обратном порядке
$halfSum = intval(array_sum($arr) / 2); // высчитываем сумму значений и делим на две примерно равные части

$arr_first = array(); // первый массив
$arr_second = array(); // второй массив
$sum1 = 0; // сумма первого массива для сравнения
$sum2 = 0; // сумма второго массива для сравнения
// перебираем отсортированный исходный массив
foreach($arr as $val){
    // сумма первого массива меньше второго 
    // и сумма второго массива больше или равна половине общей суммы
    // то очередное значение добавляется в первый массив
    // в ином случае - во второй массив
    if($sum1 <= $sum2 || $sum2 >= $halfSum){
        $arr_first[] = $val;
        $sum1 += $val;
    } else {
        $arr_second[] = $val;
        $sum2 += $val;
    }
}
//выводим суммы обоих массивов
echo array_sum($arr_first).'<br />'.array_sum($arr_second);
```

Конечно далеко не уверен, что работает корректно, но несколько раз протестил и вроде бы как все нормально сделало.

Comment: Что-то я тоже сомневаюсь) По-моему это задаче о рюкзаке, где стоимость каждого элемента 1, вес - элемент. А вместимость половина суммы массива. Как только находим решение стоимостью n/2 (где n - количество элементов в массиве) останавливаемся и восстанавливаем массив. Хотя может мне просто поспать надо (тоже не уверен) :)

Comment: Ну, если плюсуют вариант, который предложил @Котик_хочет_кушать, то всё-таки алгоритм выбран правильный, т.к. практически идентичный

Comment: Тоже (как и у @Котик) не то. Алгоритм не обеспечивает равного размера частей. 

В этом-то (одно из условий вопроса) и загвоздка.

Comment: @avp, Ответил выше ))

Comment: @Deonis Вы про Ваш алгоритм?

Comment: Да это я @avp про размеры частей. Просто несколькими секундами раньше ответил на этот же вопрос под ответом @Котик -а

Comment: Я там тоже прокомментировал. К сожалению все. Пора спать и утром рулить на дачу.

Comment: @Deonis я про правильность. По ссылке Котика как раз упоминается задача о рюкзаке :)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно предложить генетический алгоритм.

FitnessFunction понятно сумма (чем ближе к половине суммы всех элементов массива, тем круче)

Хромосома состоит из n/2 ген (ген - элемент массива).

Поиграться количеством популяции, посмотреть сколько примерно будет нужно для более менее адекватного результата. Ну и подумать как скрещивать (можно наверно сортировать гены в родителях и циклически скрещивать)

Опять же результат будет примерным (для улучшения можно несколько раз прогнать алгоритм и выбрать лучший результат)

Comment: @rasmisha

- Извините, что стер свой прошлый коммент под моим ответом, просто размышлял над доказательством того, что это - `NPC` задача.

- Не уверен, кстати, что `ff,` у которой метрика хорошести пропорциональна отклонению от полусуммы - это хороший выбор. Хотя не очень силен в генетических алгоритмах.

Comment: @Котик на счет ff вполне может быть. Просто решил поделиться вариантом, который пришел в голову и показался одним из способов найти приближенный ответ.

Comment: @Котик кстати, первая идея (не знаю насколько она правильна) как раз совпадает с вашей (по-крайней мере судя по ссылкам приведенным Вами), но не уверен опять же, что правильно распределил вес/стоимость/вместимость.

Comment: @rasmisha

- Да, мне тоже, как только я глянул на вопрос, пришла в голову идея, что, собственно, две части массива - это два рюкзака c `N / 2` элементов каждый. Но здесь не очень понятно, как **строго** установить ограничения для суммарного веса. А цена нестрогим заявлениям при работе с алгоритмами известна всем :)

- Может быть, есть какие-нибудь другие формулировки `Knapsack Problem`, которые лучше подойдут для этого случая, не проверял.

Answer (score 2):

[Вроде работает](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/WhL7w/) :) Для массива с четным количеством элементов. Для нечетного чуть подправить надо, а лениво )

Суть такая. Сортируем изначальный массив. Заполняем оба выходных массива одновременно по одному числу в каждый. В массив с меньшей суммой добавляем бОльшее число, в массив в с бОльшей суммой добавляем элемент, при добавлении которого бОльший массив так и останется с бОльшей суммой (начинаем проверять с наименьшего элемента, если так и остался с большей, значит добавляется первый элемент и т.д.).

**UPD** Проблема жадности проявляется на этапе когда выбираются максимальные элементы. Когда выбирается максимальный и один из минимальных элементов, жадность не влияет на выбор. Соответственно эту неопределенность предлагаю ветвить. Находим все множества решений исходя и того, что максимальные элементы могут принадлежать как первому-второму массиву, так и второму-первому. А затем выбираем наиболее подходящее с точки зрения минимальности разности сумм. В худшем случае будет брутфорс, жаль.

Comment: - Для `[0,1,2,2,2,3,4,7,10,40,54,60,120,127]` проявляется жадность алгоритма.

- Ваш алгоритм вернет `[127,54,10,7,4,3,2]` и `[120,60,40,0,1,2,2]`, но можно получить меньший разброс сумм, если, например, поменять `54` и `60` местами.

- *А вообще круто, что вам было не влом этим заниматься :)*

Comment: В общем, некоторые способы будут в какой-то мере правильно работать, если разрядность чисел будет примерно одинакова, НО если одно число будет значительно больше, то все сойдёт на нет. Вот даже [на вашем примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/WhL7w/6/). ))) Так что, пора со спокойной душей ложиться спать ;)

Comment: @Deonis В примере со `100500` алгоритм как раз правильно отработал - он вернул результат с минимально возможной разницей, так что видимо со спокойной душой не получится :)

Comment: Хм, да )
Можно убавить жадность проверкой увеличения разлета для j==k-1. если разность сумм увеличивается при выборе максимальных элементов, то менять их местами. Вполне вероятно, что и этого недостаточно будет.

Задачка интересная, да.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov неужели Вы из-за этого не спали?

Comment: я ночной человек, не из-за этого ))

Answer (score 0):

1. смотрим на длину массива
2. смотрим на суммы половинок
3. если равные - профит
4. если нет, смотрим разницу и запоминаем
5. *разницу* делим на 2
6. ищем *это* значение (разницу/2) в части, где больше
7. делим *ее*(разницу/4) еще на 2 и ищем *это* значение(то что получилось) в левой части
8. меняем их(то что нашли в половинках массива) местами

алгоритм прикинул на глаз, мб неправильно, проверьте, поправьте и если не правильно, простите

Comment: Я думаю, что пункты 1-4 надо немного видоизменить на поиск границы в массиве, на которой разность суммы элементов частей меняет свой знак или равны.

Comment: раз 5 прочитал. Не понял пункты 6-8 )

Comment: @Gorets, тут скорее возникает вопрос, что делать если:

1. Разница не делится на 2 нацело
2. в большей части нет этого значения
3. что делать если (7) не делится на 2 нацело
3. в меньшей части нету этого значения

Comment: @Dex, возможно, но пока что мне кажется твой алгоритм сложнее

@rasmisha, дополнил

Comment: Вот проверил ваш алгоритм на бумаге, не правильно.
1, 2, 3 и 4,5,6
6 и 15
15 - 6 = 9
9/2 = 4
в большей части это 1-й элемент
4/2 = 2
В первой части это 2-й элемент
меняем местами
1, 4, 3 и 2, 5, 6
8 = 13

Comment: @Gorets, это чисто предположение. Я твой алгоритм не проверял, кажется логичным, но задачка хорошая.

Comment: можно сделать, чтобы были не равны, а наиболее близки к равности

Comment: @Dex, согласен, мой вариант больше похож на частный случай, и я отталкивался от задачи - приравнять стороны массива, без изменения количества в их половинках, но все равно мой вариант можно взять как основу и усовершенствовать до задачи - разделения массива на 2 половины по равности их сумм их значений.

Comment: Неплохая попытка наскоком придумать алгоритм для `NPC` задачи :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно запустить бинарный поиск по ответу, а для каждого значение проверять алгоритмом для набора рюкзака, можем ли мы набрать рюкзак данного размера. Сложность O(N ** *N* logN). Если ответ есть, он находится, можно и доработать для поиска двух подмассивов минимальной разности. Это как вариант.

Answer (score -2):

1. **Отсортировать** массив.
2. Брать *суммы значений* крайних элементов массива и ***складывать их
    поочередно*** в одну из двух переменных.
3. **Если длинна массива нечётная** - прибавить к меньшей из двух переменных значение
    `центрального` элемента.

Comment: Жадный алгоритм как было уже сказано даст примерный результат.

Comment: Т. е. я его просто расписал на словах?

Comment: Ну что-то похожее по крайней мере

Comment: оформление ответа слизано с ответов тов. @Котик\_хочет\_кушать

Comment: > Если моё решение не правильное - не минусуйте XD

*Я в домике!* :-D 

Логичное возражение: *А я - мистер Нейтрон!*