# Разбиение последовательности на две, суммы которых равны или приближенные

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Есть последовательность, например:

```
{"set": [3, 3, 3, 7, 5]}
```

Необходимо, чтобы эта последовательность разделилась на две, суммы элементов которых будут равны между собой либо максимально приближены друг к другу. Во втором случае ответ должен выглядеть так:

```
{"set_1": [3, 3, 5], "set_2": [3, 7]}
```

Сначала думал найти сумму всех элементов, разделить ее пополам и через цикл отнимать. Но это не то. Последовательность может быть любой длины.

Подскажите идеи, какой алгоритм решения?

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144007/

Comment: Если из самых простых вариантов, то можно попробовать отсортировать числа и прибавлять их к двум переменным a и b. Мы берём число c из массива и сравниваем это: а + с - c + b с этим: a + b - c + b. Если первое больше, то вытащенное число прибавляем ко второй переменной. А если наоборот, к первой. Конечно, хорошую точность такой алгоритм не обеспечит, как и любой другой жадный алгоритм. Рекомендую ознакомиться с задаче о рюкзаке, которая как раз предназначена для решения такой проблемы: https://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript-beginners/thread2204050.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разделение массива по равенству двух частей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/115595/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: @Kromster По ссылке нет полноценного решения, и условие той задачи несколько отличается (требуется ещё одинаковое количество элементов).

Answer (score 3):

Описание [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144007/) уже делал, повторю до кучи:

Задача относится к классу **subset sum** (сумма подмножества) и может быть решена динамическим программированием. Переформулируя - требуется собрать подмножество с суммой `Sum/2` или максимально близкой.

Создаётся таблица длиной `Sum/2`. Нулевой элемент заполнен ненулевым значением, означающим, что сумму `0` собрать можно, остальные пока нулями.

Затем проходим по всем элементам `e` входного множества.

Для каждого проверяем ячейки таблицы **в обратном порядке**, чтобы исключить многократное использование элемента в наборе суммы.

Сумму `i` c использованием элемента e собрать можно, если существует возможная сумма `i-e`. Если сумма `i` встречается впервые, то записываем `e` в соответствующую ячейку на будущее. Тут же обновляем `best` - дистанцию, насколько набранная сумма близка к целевой.

По окончанию работы разматываем цепочку элементов, составляющих лучшую сумму. В ячейке `a[sum/2 - best]` ведь хранится слагаемое (`e`), с помощью которого получена эта сумма. В следующей ячейке, на которую указывает `e` (`a[i-e]` в основном алгоритме) - следующее слагаемое и т.д. Таким образом получается одно подмножество, а не вошедшие в него элементы образуют второе.

```js
function halfsum(arr) {
   let hsum = Math.floor(arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 2)
   let a = [-1]
   for (var i=0;i<hsum;i++) {
      a.push(0)}
   let best = hsum + 1

    arr.forEach(e => {
        for (var i=hsum;i>=e; i--){
            if ((a[i - e] !=0) & (a[i] == 0)) {
                a[i] = e;
                if (hsum - i < best) {
                   best = hsum - i;
                }
            }    
      } 
    })
    
    let id = hsum - best
    let b = []
    while (id > 0) {
        b.push(a[id]);
        id = id - a[id];
    }   
    return b;
}

console.log(halfsum([3,11,29,51,13,7]));
```

Comment: ваш алгоритм работает лучше, но почему-то на такой комбинации он не работает [3,3,4,5]

Comment: @Roman Да, Вы правы. Исходная версия на Python для этих данных работает, а здесь нужно было целочисленное деление сделать для hsum

Comment: Спасибо. Интересное решение, но в вашем алгоритме список а = [-1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 3, 7, 5, 3, 7], а список b верный.

Comment: А Вы разобрались, что лежит во **вспомогательном** массиве `a`? Результат возвращается в `b` ведь.

Comment: @MBo, равзе на отрицательных числах работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Такая реализация - нет, она рассчитана на натуральные числа.

Answer (score 1):

Функция getArrays() принимает в качетсве параметра - исходный массив, и возвращает массив, который состоит из двух массивов, которые и нужно было получить в результате этой задачи

Вот вопрос на stackoverflow, который я взял за основу, и переписал на js:
[Разделение массива по равенству двух частей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/115595/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)
В коде я описал комментариями логику работы.

```js
//подсчет суммы массива
const getSumOfArray = array => array.reduce((a, c) => a + c)

//сортировка по убыванию(деструктуризация массива нужна для того чтобы не менялся исходный массив, который будет передан в эту функцию)
const descendingSort = array => [...array].sort((a, b) => b - a)

function getArrays(innerArray) {
    //сумма исходного массива
    const sumOfInnerArray = getSumOfArray(innerArray)

    //половина суммы исходного массива
    const halfOfSum = sumOfInnerArray / 2

    //сортировка по убыванию
    const sortedArray = descendingSort(innerArray)

    //результирующие массивы:
    const resultingArray1 = []
    const resultingArray2 = []

    //сумма результирующих массивов:
    let sumOfResultingArray1 = 0
    let sumOfResultingArray2 = 0

    //проходимся по отсротированному массиву и формируем два новых
    sortedArray.forEach(element => {
        if (
            sumOfResultingArray1 <= sumOfResultingArray2 ||
            sumOfResultingArray2 >= halfOfSum
        ) {
            resultingArray1.push(element)
            sumOfResultingArray1 += element
        } else {
            resultingArray2.push(element)
            sumOfResultingArray2 += element
        }
    })

    return [resultingArray1, resultingArray2]
}

const innerArray1 = [3, 3, 3, 7, 5]

//использование
const [arr1, arr2] = getArrays(innerArray1)

console.log(`Исходный массив: [ ${innerArray1} ]`)
console.log(`Массив 1: [ ${arr1} ], Сумма: ${getSumOfArray(arr1)}`)
console.log(`Массив 2: [ ${arr2} ], Сумма: ${getSumOfArray(arr2)}`)

console.log('----------------------------')

const innerArray2 = [3, 3, 3, 7, 5, 4, 5, 6, 61, 62]

//использование без деструктуризации
const result = getArrays(innerArray2)
const array1 = result[0]
const array2 = result[1]

console.log(`Исходный массив: [ ${innerArray2} ]`)
console.log(`Массив 1: [ ${array1} ], Сумма: ${getSumOfArray(array1)}`)
console.log(`Массив 1: [ ${array2} ], Сумма: ${getSumOfArray(array2)}`)
```

Comment: Используется жадный алгоритм, который не гарантирует получение правильного решения

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, эта задача называется "Задача о рюкзаке" с некоторыми дополнениями. Разница с классической задачей в том, что надо будет собрать не один, а два "рюкзака", и следить не за тем, чтобы рюкзак был заполнен максимально ценными предметами, а за тем, чтобы вес рюкзаков был бы максимально близок друг к другу. Алгоритм решения задачи можно посмотреть здесь: https://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/zadacha-o-ryukzake.html

Comment: Я уже как-то запутался немного.. Как это правильно реализовать на JS с такой последовательностью?

Comment: @faceVB я не разбираюсь в js, не смогу написать код. Вместо того, чтобы указывать в "рюкзаке" максимальный вес, можно сложить все числа в массиве и поделить на два - получится идеал, к которому должны стремиться оба набора. Ну и реализуйте класс Pair для хранения, который будет содержать оба набора. После того, как соберёте коллекцию этих Pair, сравните и найдите наилучшую комбинацию.

Comment: Да, я пишу класс. Написал методы сортировки и суммы всех элементов. Я так думал по началу, что сумму разделю на два, и буду от половины суммы вычитать элементы и добавлять в новый сет, я не знаю как это реализовать. Если я так буду делать у меня будет следующий результат set_1 = [3, 3, 3] и set_2 = [7, 5], а это не правильно.

Comment: @faceVB Попробуйте полностью перенести описанный по ссылке алгоритм.
Класс предмет вам не нужен. У вас есть массив с числами, числа - это и есть предмет.
В классе "рюкзак" вам нужно одно поле, которое будет равно половине сумме чисел в массиве (идеал, к которому вы стремитесь)
Вместо методов calcWeigth и calcPrice вам нужен один метод calcSum, который будет считать сумму получившегося набора.
Для хранения двух массивов вам понадобится класс, назовёте например Pair.
В методе checkSet проверите то, что разница между двумя наборами в Pair минимальна.

Comment: @faceVB и вам останется только реализовать рекурсивный метод (это же возможно в js?), который будет генерировать всевозможные наборы. Ну и, разумеется, немного сгладите шероховатости.